# How do I get the creation date of a MySQL database?

Tags: mysql

In order to display some detailled information regarding customer databases in a GUI I'm currently writing, I need to know how to check in `MySQL 5.7` when a certain database has been created?

Answer (score 29):

To date, MySQL doesn't have the feature to store database creation time. Though many users requested to add this feature, they haven't implemented it yet. So, it is impossible to find database creation date using any query. We should wait for any updates having that feature in future.

By the way, as the table creation date is stored inside mysql, we can treat the creation date of the oldest table of that database as the database creation date. So, we can get this using below query:

```
SELECT
table_schema AS Database_Name, MIN(create_time) AS Creation_Time
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema = 'YOUR_DATABASE_NAME'
Group by table_schema;
```

But, obviously this is not an ideal solution.

Comment: your answer is to query create date of `table`,but the user is ask  `database`

Comment: the query works only if tables are available, it does not work for empty databases , the simplest way : just look into your path where mysql store the database-files,

Answer (score 1):

Mentioning a query that can be helpful for listing database names in descending order by creation date time. This query can be helpful.

```
select distinct table_schema as database_name,
-- table_name,
create_time
from information_schema.tables
where create_time > adddate(current_date,INTERVAL -2 DAY)
and table_schema not in('information_schema', 'mysql',
                          'performance_schema','sys')
and table_type ='BASE TABLE'
-- and table_schema = 'your database name' 
order by create_time desc
```

The above query is modified from the query listed on https://dataedo.com/kb/query/mysql/find-recently-created-tables